# Problem Declaring Array of Structure

Tags: solidity

I am trying to declare array of structure but its not accepting. I got this 
      program from internet.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
      contract NaiveBank { 
      struct Account { 
         address addr ;
        uint balance ; 
      } 
      Account accounts []; 
      function applyInterest () returns ( uint ) { 
         for ( uint i = 0; i < accounts . length ; i++) { 
            // apply 5 percent interest 
            accounts [i]. balance = accounts [i]. balance* 105 / 100; 
         } 
         return accounts . length ; 
      } 
   }
```

I am getting following error message:

> D:\SolidityContractsSelf\Remix\From Remix Site\Struct>solc
>   NaiveBank.sol NaiveBank.sol:8:18: Error: Expected ';' but got '['
>   Account accounts [];

```
             ^
```

D:>

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Account accounts [];
```

To this:

```
Account[] accounts;
```

Or better yet, to this:

```
Account[] public accounts;
```